# Most elegant way to create 'subrecord' type keeping names of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, record, postgresql-11

So I'm playing with Postgres' [`composite types`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rowtypes.html), and I cannot figure out one thing. Suppose I want to use subset of columns of certain table, or mix of different columns of several different tables used in the query, and create a record type out of them.

Logically, simple `(c.id, c.name)` should work, but it seems that column names are actually lost - it's not possible to address fields of the records by `name` and `id`, and, for example, `to_json` function cannot use field names when creating json out of this record. Using subquery `(select c.id, c.name)` is predictably failing with `subquery must return only one column` error.

I can, of course, use lateral join or common table expression to create this sub-type, but I'm thinking - if there's more elegant way?

see [`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a041f947ee7c7b97b8b68b02da5b861a) with table example and test query

```
create table test(id integer, name text, price int);

insert into test(id,name,price)
values
    (1,'name1',1),
    (2,'name2',12),
    (3,'name3',23),
    (5,'name5',4),
    (9,'name9',3);

create type sub_test as (id integer, name text);

select
    c.price,
    -- using predefined type - works
    to_json((c.id, c.name)::sub_test),
    -- creating row type on the fly - doesn't work, names are lost
    to_json((c.id, c.name)),
    -- using derived table created with lateral join - works
    to_json(d)
from test as c, lateral(select c.id, c.name) as d
```

Comment: You don't need the lateral join `select to_jsonb(t) from (select id, name from test) as t`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but what if I want to be able to use column price in the query as well?